# Processing a long list using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

```
output = mp.Queue()

def endScoreList(all_docs, query, pc, output):
    score_list = []
    for doc in all_docs:
        print "In process", pc
        score_list.append(some_score(doc, query))
        print "size of score_list is", len(score_list)
    output.put((doc, score_list))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    num_of_workers = mp.cpu_count()
    doc_list = getDocuments(query)
    ## query is a list of strings.
    ## doc_list is a list of document names
    processes = [mp.Process(target = endScoreList, args = (doc_list, x, query, output)) for x in range(num_of_workers)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    results = [output.get() for p in processes]
    print results
```

I have a list of document names `all_docs` whose data I have to compare with an input `query`. This is done using score that I get from `some_score(doc, query)`. The list of documents is ~100k. I have to get scores of all the documents. How can I make a program so that the scores are generated  parallelly. The scores are independent of each other so in the end I just have to merge all the returned list of `(doc, score)`. I tried to make a program, but I don't think it is running parallelly.

Please help me out.

I am using Windows 64-Bit/i7.

Comment: What makes you think your processes are not running in parallel?

Comment: While the code you've shown is pretty close to working, a much easier implementation is probably possible using `multiprocessing.Pool` and one of its `map` methods (`map`, `imap`, `map_async`, etc.).

Comment: @SeanPedersen it was actually very slow. I printed the size of the list with in the function and it was working the same way as it was without `multithreading`.

Comment: @Blckknght I'll try those as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to suggest what is going wrong with your current code, as the example you've shown has a number of issues (for instance, you're using `//` to introduce a comment, creating processes that call a `finalScore` function and pass `doc_list` as a parameter, neither of which are defined).

Rather than try to figure out what is going on with your code, I'd like to suggest an alternative solution that is likely to be much simpler. If you use `multiprocessing.Pool`'s `map` method, you'll get your work distributed over however many processes are in the pool.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(doc):
    return doc, some_score(doc, "query")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()
    p = mp.Pool() # default is a number of processes equal to the number of CPU cores
    scores = p.map(worker, all_docs)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

This simple version assumes that the query string is a constant. If that's not the case, you could pass it as an argument in the `map` call (or consider using `starmap` instead).

Comment: I have corrected the mistakes you pointed out in the text. Does it help you in identifying something?

Comment: Well, the general issue with your code is that you never subdivide the `doclist` between the processes. That is, each process runs on all of the documents (and so you score each one multiple times). You could probably modify your code to pass a slice of the complete doclist to each worker process, and it would probably work. I just think using `multiprocessing.Pool` is much easier.

Comment: So, you mean I should divide the whole list in like 8 parts i.e. for 8 processes and use them in the first code. Another thing I wanted to know is that how do I pass a function to `map` that has more than one argument. I have a `doc_list` and a `query`. Should I pass them as a list of tuples i.e. `(doc, query)`?

Comment: If you're creating the processes manually, yes, you'd want to split the input (or perhaps use the process number to iterate over just a portion of the contents). As for passing multiple arguments via `map`, you can either package your values into a data structure that then get unpacked in the worker function, or you can use `starmap` and it will each tuple or list into positional arguments like `worker(*arg)`. As for building the sequence, I'd suggest using a generator expression: `p.starmap(worker, ((doc, query) for doc in all_docs))`

Comment: Thanks, I get your point. 
Basically, `map` or `starmap` saves me from the trouble of creating processes manually and I also don't have to slice my data. I'll try this with starmap and see how it performs.